# how to get the coordinates of Browser?

Tags: firefox-addon, xpcom

I have  created Firefox extension using XPCOM . I want to get coordinates of client area of browser?
How to get coordinates of client area of browser using XPCOM?
please help me.
thanks,
Nandkuamar

Comment: What do you mean? Are you looking for the geographic coordinates or the browser coordinates in the screen?

Answer (score 1):

1. If you have a window variable for the content area in question, just use its `screenX`/`screenY` properties.
2. If you have a window variable for the browser in question, use its `content` property to access the current tab's window, and then follow step 1.
3. If you don't have a variable yet, you can ask the [window mediator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIWindowMediator) for one.